# differences between Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract and Zend_View_Helper_Abstract

Tags: php, zend-framework

I would like to know the differences between two helpers `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract` and `Zend_View_Helper_Abstract` in Zend framework which I did not understand.

Comment: You did not accept any answers yet. Can you please review the given answers and either accept the most helpful **or** [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5105808/edit) to point out why none of the given answers answer your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like their names suggest:

An ActionHelper is for reusable functionality needed in the actions of your Controllers, while a ViewHelper is for reusable functionality in your View Templates.

From http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html

> Action Helpers allow developers to inject runtime and/or on-demand functionality into any Action Controllers that extend Zend_Controller_Action. Action Helpers aim to minimize the necessity to extend the abstract Action Controller in order to inject common Action Controller functionality.

From http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html

> In your view scripts, often it is necessary to perform certain complex functions over and over: e.g., formatting a date, generating form elements, or displaying action links. You can use helper classes to perform these behaviors for you.

The main idea is to encapsulate often used functionality into objects, instead of recreating that functionality over again or using inheritance for it (which would bloat the base class and violate the Single Responsibility Principle). ZF distinguishes between ViewHelpers and ActionHelpers because they have different responsibility. ActionHelpers are used in helping handling a request, while ViewHelpers are used in helping rendering the model.

Answer (score 0):

Simple rule of thumb if your view helper needs to know about your model (using Zend_Db_Table) then you are doing it wrong instead use action helper . Action helper benefits you have access to hooks such as preDispatch and postDispatch.

View helper benefits you can use it inside action controller also e.g echo `$this->view->myHelper();`  And I have see this used very off-ten.

Comment: This is incorrect. ViewHelper may access the Model, as long as they dont alter it's state. Also the Model is not just the classes derived from Zend_Db_Table. The Model is not just the database.

Comment: yes you are correct but I am generalizing the situation .Normally model is of type DbTable and In True MVC , V has no idea about M .

Comment: sorry, but no :) The Model isnt *normally* the DbTable. This is a common misconception that stems from frameworks using ActiveRecord. In MVC M is all classes not VC where VC = presentation layer. M can be persistence layers, service layers, domain layers, mappers, etc. - also in "true" MVC, V is usually observing M, which means M doesnt know about V, but V knows about M, which makes sense since the role of V is to update when M changes. See http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#ModelViewController

Comment: yes you are correct as always I probably should delete my answer .